# Why is it that in DDO (Dungeons & Dragons Online), paralyzed characters still "move"?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons-online

This has been annoying me for the past months, well since I've been playing Dungeons & Dragons Online, that paralyzed characters still move around when getting "paralyzed". Not sure if it's the game, my client installation, my connection, or God punishing me for playing so much. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: For reference, by the D&D third edition rules (http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#paralyzed), paralyzed means a character cannot physically move or take actions, although it can take purely mental actions like concentrating on an existing spell. At one point in my campaign, a player was effectively paralyzed by Strength-draining poison, dropped to the ground under the weight of his own clothing, then skidded from the room using his own Fly spell like a ragdoll pulled by a string.

Answer (score 2):

Its a known long standing bug. Devs have mentioned that they "finally fixed it" a few times but it still happens quite often especially if you paralyze them when they are moving. It used to be more common though, so they are improving.

Comment: While I didn't know it was a bug it certainly looks like one--paralyzation doesn't always abort existing movement.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is lag between the player using an effect that causes paralysis, that instruction being sent from the client to the server, then the server updating the monster, and finally the server sending the updated data back to the client.

This is why the monsters appear to 'slide' to their updated position.

There's no real way to cure lag problems without letting the client override the server update, and that would open up endless avenues for hacks.

Comment: Not quite, they simply get caught in run animation. You can do this in the lobster via tumble. If you start a tumble when you get paralyzed then you will finish the movement even though yous till have the effect. Going one step further you can do the same thing and add in an attack and continue attacking while paralyzed.